# Mapbox doesn't find peaks/mountains

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

When I try, for example
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/king mountain.json?access_token=...

or

https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/king mountain.json?types=poi&limit=10&access_token=...

I don't see the [King Mountain in Oregon](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=king%20mountain%2C%20oregon#map=17/43.81035/-118.86866). Same for [Gobblers Knob](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/357329876). I thought that Mapbox used Openstreetmap, why does it not find peaks by name?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You are correct. Part of the Mapbox data is coming from Open Street Map. That is the data that you see on the map, but the Geocoding API operates on the different datasets. So there would be cases that you see data on the map but not able to find them with the geocoder. Mapbox Geocoder does not support mountain peaks as for now.

It will be helpful to submit your this feedback via Mapbox [geocoder feedback tool](https://labs.mapbox.com/geocoder-feedback/).

Comment: Nope, it still does not find the King Mountain in Oregon. or the hill gobblers knob, in Oregon. I guess it's just got very different feature set than Openstreetmap Nominatim.